# Vue JS 0.12 Dynamic Components

Tags: javascript, components, browserify, vue.js

I upgraded to Vue 0.12 but it's left me with a tricky problem.

I'm using Browserify/Vueify to transpile and concatenate single file component definitions. In my app component I "require" the needed components and assign to keys in the components object then use v-component="x" in the template to mount them.

Now 0.12 only allows that behaviour on table elements,how could I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use component name as a tag name like so:

`<component-name></component-name>`

Alternatively you could do: `<component is="component-name"></component>`

Comment: Many thanks, Azamat.

`<component is="x"></component>` worked a treat!